# How to get Name of Role in Razor View?

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am new in Asp.net identity. How to get Name of Role in Razor View?
My controller

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Users()
    {
        var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = RoleManager;
        return View(users);
    }
 private ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
    }
```

I tried through the property roles.But there is no name
view

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>
            @item.UserName
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Roles
        </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have sent `RoleManager` to the view by `ViewBag`. You can use role manager to get name of the roles in the view like this:

```
@string.Join(" | ", item.Roles.Select(r=>ViewBag.Roles.FindById(r.RoleId).Name))
```

But always consider making a view model for views and fill your data to view models in the controllers instead of directly processing them in the views.